# Why the return type for frames is WebDriver in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, iframe, frames

Why the return type for frames is Web Driver in Selenium .
Consider the below code where the driver switches to the frame. But why the return type is Web Driver for the below code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(int/string/webelement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because driver interacts with the element of currently focused document (page) and iframe is separate document which embedded on another document (e.g. webpage).

So to interacts with the iframe's element we need to focus on that particular frame that's why it returns webdriver instance which is currently focused.

Refer the selenium document : `WebDriver` interface

> ```
> WebDriver frame(int index);
>
> /**
>  * Select a frame by its name or ID. Frames located by matching name attributes are always given
>  * precedence over those matched by ID.
>  *
>  * @param nameOrId the name of the frame window, the id of the &lt;frame&gt; or &lt;iframe&gt;
>  *        element, or the (zero-based) index
>  * @return This driver focused on the given frame
>  * @throws NoSuchFrameException If the frame cannot be found
>  */
> ```

Comment: Can you please share the selenium document , I am unable to access the document you have attached.

Comment: Hey @Aditya, In selenium library, there is one package named `org.openqa.selenium;` and there is one class name `WebDriver.class`. You can find the above mentioned code over there. To open the class file just control+click on `WebDriver` in your code where you have written like `WebDriver driver = somedriver`.